# What does "tracktable trajectories" mean in this context?

Tags: dynamical-systems

In a dynamical system what does the following point to?

"What range of trajectories seem to be trackable by XYZ method?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it is a simple typo. The appropriate term is "trackable".

Comment: Or, maybe, "tractable".

Comment: @Anatly, yes you are right. I've edited the question